# How to do calculus with split-complex (hyperbolic) numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, semi-riemannian-geometry, split-complex-numbers

TL;DR: how do I define a "split-holomorphic" function?

As far as I've heard, there is a notion of split-complex numbers: $z = x+uy$, with $u\not\in \Bbb R $ and $u^2 = 1$. One defines the conjugate as $\overline{z} = x - uy$ and the modulus as $|z| = \sqrt{|z\overline{z}|}$, where the absolute value inside the root is the one for real numbers, as usual.
Apparently this can be used to study the pseudo-Riemannian geometry of $\Bbb L^2 = \Bbb R^2_1$ in the same way thay $\Bbb C$ is identified with $\Bbb R^2$.

But these split-complex numbers form a ring only, and not a field: elements in the diagonals don't have multiplicative inverses. Incidentally, these diagonals correspond to lightlike directions in $\Bbb L^2$ (and such directions cause every sort of problems).

I don't know if there is a standard notation for this set of split-complex numbers, but given a function of said set to itself, how do I define things like "being holomorphic"? I can't make sense of the limit $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}$$ since $h$ could approach zero from lightlike directions. Do I just ignore these directions? Most likely I'm overthinking this.

We could define continuity of $f$ by continuity of its components, and work formally with the above limit to obtain a revised version of the CR equations, and say that $f$ is split-holomorphic if the revised CR equations hold and if the partial derivatives of the components are continuous (copying the Looman-Menchoff theorem), but I am speculating too much and I am unsure about these things.

> What is the correct way to do calculus with split-complex numbers, if this is possible? More references are also welcome.

P.s.: there is a nice book called "Geometry of Minkowski Space-Time", by Zampetti, et al, but they do a more algebraic approach and do not talk about the things I'm asking.

Comment: You can't in general divide by split-complex numbers, so if there is any such generalization it won't work this way. As a side note, the topological definition of continuity should apply because it's about as general as it gets, so no need to spend time worrying about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've probably found an answer in the past 4 years, but just in case anyone else is curious split-complex analysis is typically referred to using the term "motor variable", and a notion of holomorphic functions can be found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_variable#D-holomorphic_functions

Comment: I had figured out the bare minimum for what I needed back then, but I have never heard the term "motor variable" before, so this page and the references therein are still relevant and useful. Thank you!